# Instantiate a certain amount of prefabs, unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I wondered how i can instantiate a certain amount of prefabs c#.

ex:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
{
//Instantiate 20 prefabs
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? How do you normally instantiate one?

Comment: Im making a inventory system, so i have a variable called 'Space'. I want to instantiate as many inventory slots as the value of space. I have tried: count = space; If(count > space){instantiate(prefab);}

Comment: Well, the answer, as Sayse pointed out, is pretty straightforward. Generally you use Instantiate() in order to instantiate an object, right? Just call it in a loop :) (changing the coordinates among the objects, obviously). I hope it's clear.

Comment: I tried that but when i do that it just keep instantiating :c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the button is pressed, run a loop that loops until the `Space` value `-1` is reached then instantiate a prefab each time in the loop. This should be done in the `Update` function. It shouldn't keep instantiating if you do this correctly.

```
int Space = 20;
public GameObject prefab;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
    {
        //Instantiate 20 prefabs
        for (int i = 0; i < Space; i++)
        {
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab);
            obj.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a simple method with a single integer parameter, allowing for you to specify how many enemies you would like to create. You are most likely going to need to handle their position with some other logic, unless it is being handled within the inventory slot object itself.

```
public GameObject enemyPrefab;

//runs every frame, to check for the key press in this case
public void Update ()
{
    //did we press the specified key? (C)
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        //call our method to create our enemies!
        CreateEnemies(20);
    }
}    

public void CreateEnemies (int enemies)
{
    //the amount of enemies we want to have
    //run through this loop until we hit the amount of enemies we want
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies; i++)
    {
        //create the new enemy based on the provided prefab
        Instantiate(enemyPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```